# how to use customs fonts in emails or email templates

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

how to use customs fonts in emails or email templates Why we cant use custom fonts in emails, why @font-face style is not supported by most of the mail providers

Comment: Because you spend all your time just making stuff line-up in Outlook.

Comment: Some email clients support `@font-face`, some don’t. The “how to use customs fonts” question is addressed in many existing SO questions. The “why [...] not supported” question isn’t really constructive.

Comment: To answer your question, emails require all css to be inline.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply put.. you can't. Or rather, you shouldn't due to lack of support.

The only way to use custom fonts is by creating images for the text. That may or may not be feasible depending upon the amount of text.

Comment: really... then why I can see emails in most email clients with web fonts

Comment: @Pooya you **do** see that this is a **2012** question right. Things have improved over the last couple years. However, it's still not an absolute good idea to rely on font-face in emails. But as long as you have fall back options, it should be okay.

Comment: look at Jon's answer. the article is written on 2012.

Comment: I Know.. and look at what's NOT supported. Just because things work on YOUR email client, that doesn't mean they should be used assuming they work for everyone in the world. There's no point in arguing this.. use what you want. I'll stick to what I know is solid.

Comment: You can use @font-face with a fallback to e.g. Arial - some clients support it.

Answer (score 10):

While the answer above may have been true up until now. Looks like the answer may be changing.

Good email marketing design is about graceful degradation. While some major email clients do not support web fonts, some do... including clients on mobile devices. If your willing to make sure that your fall back fonts do not break your design in an unacceptable way then campaign monitor has a great article about the state of support for different clients and best practices.

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3897/using-web-fonts-in-email

Comment: Link is not working, the article is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

Atleast you can always put pictures instead of text just like in the good old times ;-)

Comment: most of the times pictures will not be shown, mail clients tend to block them.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with some of the previous answers saying that you cant or shouldnt.

A lot of modern email clients do have support for web fonts using the @import and @FONT_FACE method.

Whilst the list of email clients that will support these fonts inst exhaustive, they are all still in the list of 10 most used clients.

Clients that will support these methods are:

AOL Mail

Native Android mail app (not Gmail app)

Apple Mail

iOS Mail

Outlook 2000

Outlook.com app

When using web fonts just make sure you provide a fallback web-safe font for clients that dont want to play ball, not setting a fallback web-safe font will default the font to something like Times New Roman.

As others have said, if you absolutely need a font that isnt supported which is important to your design (for example: in a header), it may be best to make the text as part of the image. Just be aware that in email clients that dont load images, it may be unclear what your email is about.

You can read more about web-font best practices within emails [here](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts)

Answer (score -3):

If ya wanna use 'em, just copy and paste them from your Microsoft Office Word. It worked for me. I used Live and ProtonMail to test it, and  used 2 different browsers (Chrome and Opera).

Comment: Nope, a heavy mistake in this; if he recipient has not the font you pasted, he'll not see it. It'll be replaced by a default font. Yeah web font should be used.